# Laravel 4 - Update the values of the child table "persons" and at the same time the values of the parent table "users"

Tags: php, laravel-4, parent, eloquent

I'm using the framework Laravel.

I have 2 tables (Users and Persons). I want to update the values of the child table "persons" and at the same time the values of the parent table "users". I have an edit.blade.php where I made my form where I store the values from the database inside input fields.

Table Users

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `festival_aid`.`users` (
  `user_id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `user_email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `user_password` CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `user_salt` CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `user_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_modified` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `user_deleted` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `user_lastlogin` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `user_locked` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `user_token` VARCHAR(128) NULL,
  `user_confirmed` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`, `person_id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `user_email_UNIQUE` (`user_email` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_users_persons1_idx` (`person_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_users_persons1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`person_id`)
    REFERENCES `festival_aid`.`persons` (`person_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Table Persons

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `festival_aid`.`persons` (
  `person_id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `person_firstname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `person_surname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `person_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  `person_modified` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  `person_deleted` TIMESTAMP NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`person_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Edit action

```
public function edit($person_id)
    {
        $person = Person::find($person_id);
        //$person = Person::with('user')->orderBy('person_id');

        return View::make('persons.edit')
            ->with('person', $person);
    }
```

Update action

```
public function update($person_id)
    {
        $rules = array();
        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('persons/' . $person_id . '/edit')
                ->withErrors($validator);
        } else {
            //$person = Person::with('user')->orderBy('person_id');
            $person = Person::find($person_id);

            $person->person_firstname      = Input::get('person_firstname');
            $person->person_surname      = Input::get('person_surname');
            //$person->user->user_username = Input::get('user_username');
            //$person->user->user_surname = Input::get('user_surname');
            //$person->user->user_email = Input::get('user_email');

            $person->save();

            Session::flash('message', 'Successfully updated user!');
            return Redirect::to('persons');
        }
    }
```

Edit view

```
 <legend>Edit {{ $person->person_firstname }}</legend>

    {{ HTML::ul($errors->all()) }}

    {{ Form::model($person->user, array('route' => array('persons.update', $person->person_id), 'method' => 'PUT')) }}

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('firstname', 'Firstname') }}
        {{ Form::text('person_firstname', $value = $person->person_firstname, array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Firstname')) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('surname', 'Surname') }}
        {{ Form::text('person_surname', $value = $person->person_surname, array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Surname')) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('username', 'Username') }}

        {{ Form::text('user_username', $value = $person->user->user_username, array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Username')) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('email', 'Email') }}
        {{ Form::text('user_email', $value = $person->user->user_email, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('Password') }}
        {{ Form::password('user_password', array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Password')) }}
    </div>

    {{ Form::submit('Edit the User!', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}

    {{ Form::close() }}
@stop
```

User migration

```
Schema::table('users', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
        $table->increments('user_id');
            $table->string('user_email');
            $table->timestamp('user_created');
            $table->timestamp('user_modified');
            $table->timestamp('user_deleted');
            $table->timestamp('user_lastlogin');
            $table->timestamp('user_locked');

            $table->foreign('person_id')
                ->references('id')->on('persons')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Person migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('persons', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('person_id');

            $table->string('person_firstname');
            $table->string('person_surname');
        });
    }
```

Model User

```
class User extends Eloquent  {

    protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';

    public function persons()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Person');
    }

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Model Person

```
class Person extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'persons';

    protected $primaryKey = 'person_id';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

My problem is that the update action only updates the values from the persons table and not from the users table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

public function update($person_id)
    {

```
    $rules = array();
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('persons/' . $person_id . '/edit')
            ->withErrors($validator);
    } else {

        $user = User::find($person_id); // <= ADD THIS
        $person = Person::find($person_id);

        $person->person_firstname      = Input::get('person_firstname');
        $person->person_surname      = Input::get('person_surname');

        $user->user_username = Input::get('user_username'); // <= ADD THIS
        $user->user_email = Input::get('user_email'); // <= ADD THIS

        $person->save();
        $user->save();

        Session::flash('message', 'Successfully updated user!');
        return Redirect::to('persons');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the Laravel docs, when updating a belongsTo relationship, you may use the associate method. This method will set the foreign key on the child model:

```
$person->users()->associate($person);

$person->save();
```

Reference:

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models